# textblob on django + apache on aws gives MissingCorpusError

Tags: python, django, apache, nltk, textblob

I have AWS linux running with apache and django. I have installed textbob extension and it works well through the python shell. However, when I use it in views.py it always gives me MissingCorpusError.

I have downloaded the corpus already (**python -m textblob.download_corpora**) and the module works fine from the python shell. What can be the problem? Have been stuck on this thing since a couple of days now.

Below is the error message I get,

> Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature.To
>   download the necessary data, simply run    python -m
>   textblob.download_corporaor use the NLTK downloader to download the
>   missing data: http://nltk.org/data.htmlIf this doesn't fix the
>   problem, file an issue at https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues.